# Date string to Date in C# - day of week was incorrect

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

Trying to convert the following but am having difficulty.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?
Any help appreciated thanks.

```
dateString = "Mon Aug 7 15:32:52 GMT+0900 2007";//Actionscript date string
dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss G'M'Tzzz yyyy",
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Getting the following error:

System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

August 7, 2007 was a Tuesday.

Comment: Just got the dates I was given - didn't think to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, the 7 august 2007 was a tuesday is suppose :-)